# The Retrieved Data are not in Ascending order?

Tags: android

I am using Android 2.1 platform, I have 7 contacts in my emulator when I try to retrieve the email of the contacts it will be working but not in the order I saved in the contact List.If I created a new contact with new email,it will go to the last.I am using this code.

**Code**

```
public class RetrieveData extends Activity {

ListView lvItem;
private Button btnAdd;
String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listview);  
   btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
   itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
   lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
   btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           GetEmails();

       }
   }); 
}

private void GetEmails()
    {


    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        {               
            emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
            contactlist.add(emailAddress);
            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        emails.close();

    }
    cursor.close(); 
}
}
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="288dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.03" >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Retrieve"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"  />


</LinearLayout>
```

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Tested Code Below,

```
package stack.examples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RetrieveData extends Activity {

    ListView lvItem;
    private Button btnAdd;
    String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
    ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView);  
       btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
       itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
       lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
       btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               GetEmails();

           }
       }); 
    }

    private void GetEmails()
        {


        ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {       
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
            while (emails.moveToNext()) 
            {               
                emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                contactlist.add(emailAddress);

            }
            emails.close();
            sortList(contactlist);
            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        cursor.close(); 
    }  
    private static void sortList(List<String> aItems){
        Collections.sort(aItems, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
      }
}
```

Comment: You done a great job, I appreciate your work within no time you did the work to me.

Comment: You done a great job, I appreciate your work within no time you did the work to me.A small editing is required that means The email will be in Ascending order according to the Contact list.With those my questions and your answers I have known something about the DataBase ans Cursors, so Let me try to do the remaining editing by myself, if I don't get I will call you through this site OK .Nandri PONMALAR anna.

Comment: Akka Nja nenache ninga Anna ayirikkumo appidi..eena unga name vandhu Ponmalar atinale ta..

Comment: Akka enakku solution kidachachu .....only 5% is remaining for my requirement.. :)

Comment: I am using your code at the end I used collections.sort(arraylist);.correct ?  now it will print in ascending  order..thank you

Comment: I tried a lot..but can't..actually now I get all name number and Email from my contacts OK, BUT  If  I create a new contact having name and number not email,  That contact will take the  email ID  from the contact just down to it.that means,the name  C has no email ID but  D has email ID , C will take D's email ID? u got it
so C and D have the same Email ID ? is d  FIRST problem

Answer (score 3):

Use **orderBy** in the query in

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

like

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, columnName + " ASC");
```

Similarly for `descending` use **DESC**.

Comment: @Dheeresh I am fine and hope you are doing good. Your solution is ok but if we can get the sorted data thru the db then there is no need to use collections else it is a very good approach.

Comment: I know your right it looks here he has  two nested quires .... look once more and see where he put orderBy and what in that?

Comment: Doesn't matter how many nested queries there are he can use the last argument for that AFAIK.

Comment: Hello i am using Shukla's code has one error in columnName, please I am a beginner in database, the error is columnName is cannot be resolved a variable.

Comment: @BigBoss Dheeresh is right you are using nested queries and when your final output will come it will not be sorted so I will recommend go with dheeresh's solution and still if you want to use mine then pass the name of the column in place of columnName over which you want your data sorted.

Answer (score 1):

as looks that you have two nested quires so not looks easy to implement the optimal solution which is providing order by in query. so `if that is not possible then you can try`

can use Collections.sort to sorting array list of  string `ArrayList<String>`

```
 Collections.sort(arrayList)
```

Comment: tell me please, where do I use this collection.sort(arrayList) in my code

Comment: where both while loop is completed and you have filled you arrayList with data ........

Comment: I will check the code any way thanks for Dheeresh and Vineet Shukla...........keep in touch?

I have to learn more about android, I have only 2 month experience.

Comment: I got the solution But small mistake, i will tell you an example 
my list contain Abhilash,Arul,Hari,Karthik... etc the Email will be display according to the Contact list, means first Abhilash's mail ID, second Arul mail ID then etc....................
for this will I add any other code for my project ?